# uwamp - What is best pratice when it comes to upgrading?

Tags: uwamp

We currently run Uwamp 2.2.1.

Versiojn 3.1.0 is available. What i9s best practice when upgrading. i.e. how do do it? We are new to Uwamp, bit we successfully run an internal website based on mysql.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice when you do such a change of version (2.2.1->3.1.0) is :

1- Save your website (to a zip for example)
2- Save your MySQL database (in phpMyAdmin of the old UwAmp with the export option...)
3- Install the new version of UwAmp 3.1.0
4- Import your saves (database and website) in the new version of UwAmp.

Tell me if you want more detail...